# Не запускается discord бот

Tags: python, discord

Когда запускаю бота то он сразу выключается

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = "$")

@client.event

async def function():
    print("Bot connected")


@client.command( pass_context = True)

token = ("token.txt","r").readline()

client.run(token)
```

Comment: В коде обнаружил несколько ошибок . На строчке с чтетением файла пропущенно слово open т.е token = ("token.txt","r").readline() надо заменить на token =open("token.txt","r").readline() и  @client.command( pass_context = True) лишняя собачка т.е client.command( pass_context = True)

Comment: Проверьте что файл token.txt находится в рядом с кодом . И возвращайтесь на форум добавив в вопрос саму ошибку , а не только код.